# Debezium JdbcSinkConnector TRUNCATE Table event failed

Tags: debezium

I have configured a Debezium mysql source connector which enabled truncate table event. The following is the configuration of the source connector:

```
{
    "name": "poc-mysql-connector3",
    "config": {
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
        "database.hostname": "poc-cdkrdsstack-pocrdsaac1f832-y8yzv30zxlzu.cmmpsq6kuqgl.ap-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
        "database.port": "3306",
        "database.user": "admin",
        "database.password": "password",
        "database.server.id": "838686697",
        "database.dbname": "pocrds",
        "database.sslmode": "SSL_MODE",
        "database.server.name": "b-1.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-3.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-2.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098",
        "tasks.max":"1",
        "topic.prefix": "pocrds5",
        "skipped.operations": "none",
        
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.pocrds.internal",
        "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "b-1.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-3.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-2.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098",
        "schema.history.internal.consumer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.mechanism": "AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.jaas.config": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "schema.history.internal.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
        "schema.history.internal.producer.security.protocol": "SASL_SSL",
        "schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.mechanism": "AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.jaas.config": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "schema.history.internal.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
        
        
        "database.history.kafka.topic": "poc-mysql-history-cdc",
        "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "b-1.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-3.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098,b-2.pocmskcluster.7r7ye8.c2.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9098",
        "database.history.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.sasl.mechanism":"AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "database.history.sasl.jaas.config":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "database.history.sasl.client.callback.handler.class":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",

        "database.history.producer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.mechanism":"AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.jaas.config":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "database.history.producer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",

        "database.history.consumer.security.protocol":"SASL_SSL",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.mechanism":"AWS_MSK_IAM",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.jaas.config":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
        "database.history.consumer.sasl.client.callback.handler.class":"software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
        "include.schema.changes": "true",
        "snapshot.mode":"when_needed",

        "tombstones.on.delete": "true",

        "key.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": true,       
        "key.converter.region": "ap-east-1",
        "key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": true,
        "key.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "key.converter.registry.name": "poc-rds-cdc-key",

        "value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
        "value.converter.region": "ap-east-1",
        "value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": true,
        "value.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "value.converter.registry.name": "poc-rds-cdc-value"



    }
    
}
```

Everything is work fine and I can find the truncate table event in the kafka Topic

Key:

Value:

```
{
    "before": null,
    "after": null,
    "source": {
        "version": "2.5.1.Final",
        "connector": "mysql",
        "name": "pocrds5",
        "ts_ms": 1706698615000,
        "snapshot": {
            "string": "false"
        },
        "db": "pocrds",
        "sequence": null,
        "table": {
            "string": "testing"
        },
        "server_id": 838686697,
        "gtid": null,
        "file": "mysql-bin-changelog.000086",
        "pos": 611,
        "row": 0,
        "thread": null,
        "query": null
    },
    "op": "t",
    "ts_ms": {
        "long": 1706698615867
    },
    "transaction": null
}
```

Header: {}

Then, I deploy the Debezium JdbcSinkConnector with the following configuration:

```
{
    "name": "poc-mysql-sink-connector2",
    "config": {
        "heartbeat.interval.ms": "3000",                                                            
        "autoReconnect":"true",
        "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",  
        "tasks.max": "1",  
        "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://poc-cdkrdsstack-pocrdssinke648d8a7-xn9zt3aoqgau.cmmpsq6kuqgl.ap-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/pocrds_sink",   
        "connection.username": "admin",  
        "connection.password": "password",  
        "insert.mode": "upsert",  
        "delete.enabled": "true",  
        "primary.key.mode": "record_key",  
        "schema.evolution": "basic",  
        "database.time_zone": "UTC",
        "auto.evolve": "true",
        "auto.create":"true",          
        "truncate.enabled": "true",
        "table.name.format": "${topic}",
        "topics.regex":"pocrds2.+",
        "pk.mode": "record_key",
        "pk.fields": "id",

        "transforms": "rename",
        "transforms.rename.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
        "transforms.rename.regex": "pocrds2\\.[^.]+\\.([^.]+)",
        "transforms.rename.replacement": "$1",

        "key.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": true,       
        "key.converter.region": "ap-east-1",
        "key.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": true,
        "key.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "key.converter.registry.name": "poc-rds-cdc-key",

        "value.converter": "com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.kafkaconnect.AWSKafkaAvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
        "value.converter.region": "ap-east-1",
        "value.converter.schemaAutoRegistrationEnabled": true,
        "value.converter.avroRecordType": "GENERIC_RECORD",
        "value.converter.registry.name": "poc-rds-cdc-value"

    
    }
}
```

The connector is work fine if there is no truncate table event. However, when truncate table event is pushed to the kafka topic, the corresponding table can be truncated successfully, however, the connector will be failed forever with the following error

`org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception. at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:632) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:350) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:250) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:219) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:204) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:259) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.Plugins.lambda$withClassLoader$1(Plugins.java:236) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: JDBC sink connector failure at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:96) at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:601) ... 11 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to process a sink record at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.flushBuffer(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:210) at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.lambda$flushBuffers$2(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:188) at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1337) at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.flushBuffers(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:188) at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.execute(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:149) at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnectorTask.put(JdbcSinkConnectorTask.java:103) ... 12 more Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException:` **`Cannot write to table testing with no key fields defined.`** `at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.getSqlStatement(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:355) at io.debezium.connector.jdbc.JdbcChangeEventSink.flushBuffer(JdbcChangeEventSink.java:201) ... 17 more`

I suspected that the truncate table event does not have any key in the kafka message which cause the error of the connector.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

I have tried that if I do not emit the truncate table event from the source connector (i.e. removed "skipped.operations": "none" setting), the connector will not encountered any error, but of course, it cannot handle truncate table event. Once the configure is enabled, the table can be truncated but the connector will be failed forever after the table is truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having reviewed the source code of debezium JdbcSinkConnector
https://github.com/debezium/debezium-connector-jdbc/tree/v2.5.1.Final

Fixed the following code on JdbcChangeEventSink

```
if (sinkRecordDescriptor.isTruncate()) {

            if (!config.isTruncateEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Truncates are not enabled, skipping truncate for topic '{}'", sinkRecordDescriptor.getTopicName());
                continue;
            }

            // Here we want to flush the buffer to let truncate having effect on the buffered events.
            flushBuffers(updateBufferByTable);

            flushBuffers(deleteBufferByTable);

            try {
                final TableDescriptor table = checkAndApplyTableChangesIfNeeded(tableId, sinkRecordDescriptor);
                writeTruncate(dialect.getTruncateStatement(table));
            }
            catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new ConnectException("Failed to process a sink record", e);
            }
        }
        else if (sinkRecordDescriptor.isDelete()) {

            if (!config.isDeleteEnabled()) {
                LOGGER.debug("Deletes are not enabled, skipping delete for topic '{}'", sinkRecordDescriptor.getTopicName());
                continue;
            }

            RecordBuffer tableIdBuffer = deleteBufferByTable.computeIfAbsent(tableId, k -> new RecordBuffer(config));
            List<SinkRecordDescriptor> toFlush = tableIdBuffer.add(sinkRecordDescriptor);

            flushBuffer(tableId, toFlush);
        }
        else {

            if (deleteBufferByTable.get(tableId) != null && !deleteBufferByTable.get(tableId).isEmpty()) {
                // When an insert arrives, delete buffer must be flushed to avoid losing an insert for the same record after its deletion.
                // this because at the end we will always flush inserts before deletes.

                flushBuffer(tableId, deleteBufferByTable.get(tableId).flush());
            }

            Stopwatch updateBufferStopwatch = Stopwatch.reusable();
            updateBufferStopwatch.start();
            RecordBuffer tableIdBuffer = updateBufferByTable.computeIfAbsent(tableId, k -> new RecordBuffer(config));
            List<SinkRecordDescriptor> toFlush = tableIdBuffer.add(sinkRecordDescriptor);
            updateBufferStopwatch.stop();

            LOGGER.trace("[PERF] Update buffer execution time {}", updateBufferStopwatch.durations());
            flushBuffer(tableId, toFlush);
        }
```

Used "else if" instead of "if"

After deployed, the problem seems fixed.